# In memory HSQL database hibernate query returning empty result set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have written an api that uses spring-boot and hibernate to read data from a locally hosted database, currently it only uses the built in session factory. The plan is to move this database into memory using HSQL I have achieved this using the spring xml notation:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:import.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

And using the configuration bean as below:

```
@Configuration
public class hsqlConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
              .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
              .addScript("classpath:import.sql")
              .build();
     }
}
```

The first query of the system works fine - AS Below:

```
public List<SectionAnswerBean> getSectionAnswer(List<Integer> answerIds, List<Integer> sectionIds)  {
    //SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    String hql = "SELECT A.id AS answerId, A.sectionId AS sectionId, A.questionId AS questionId " +
           "FROM Answer A " +
           "WHERE id IN (:answers) " +
           "AND A.sectionId IN (:sections)";
    Query q = session.createQuery(hql)
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SectionAnswerBean.class));
    q.setParameterList("answers", answerIds);
    q.setParameterList("sections", sectionIds);
    List<SectionAnswerBean> sectionAnswer = q.list();
    session.close();
    return sectionAnswer;

}
```

But the second query which is (below) always returns 0:

```
 public List<SectionRequirementBean> getSectionRequirementForAnswer(List<Integer> answerIds)  {
    //SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = getMySessionFactory().openSession();

    String hql = "SELECT ARM.requirementId AS requirementId, A.sectionId AS sectionId " +
            "FROM AnswerRequirementMapping ARM, Answer A " +
            "WHERE ARM.answerId IN (:answers) " +
            "AND ARM.answerId = A.id";
    Query q = session.createQuery(hql)
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SectionRequirementBean.class));
    q.setParameterList("answers", answerIds);
    List<SectionRequirementBean> sectionRequirments = q.list();
    return sectionRequirments;
}
```

Seems to clear the database, I believe there is something wrong with the way I'm auto wiring in the session factory into the data access object, this can be seen below:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}

public SessionFactory getMySessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setMySessionFactory(SessionFactory mySessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

Does anybody have any tips on where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Actually you need HQL join. Don't try to join them in SQL Oracle style using `WHERE` section. Can't say exactly without your entities code but should be like this `FROM AnswerRequirementMapping ARM JOIN Answer A` and remove the `AND ARM.answerId = A.id`